# Issue with creating a checkbox in angular grid and also not binding with my controller

Tags: html, angularjs, controller, angular-grid

I am not able to make checkboxes in angular-grid in angularjs and i have used celltemplate but its not binding with my controller
I have tried in my controller:

```
"cellTemplate":'<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="row.isSelected" ng-click=" $scope.gridOptions.selectRow($event,row)">
```

I am using angular-grid

Comment: Please post your code so that we can see where the problem might be.

Comment: grid ? which grid ? ag-grid ? kendo ? ui ? There are quite some of them.

Comment: Could you explain what are you trying to do  and using which grid type?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we have achieved putting a checkbox inside of a ui-grid:

Need to use a template in the column. I have included an ng-click, which needs extra handling

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
      data: $scope.yourData,
      columnDefs: [
            {
                field: "selected",
  cellTemplate: "
  <div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\">
     <span ng-cell-text>
        <input type=\"checkbox\" ng-model=\"row.entity.selected\" 
          ng-disabled=\"row.entity.checkBoxDisabled\" 
          ng-click=\"$event.stopPropagation();grid.appScope.hasChanged()\">
       </span>
   </div>
  "
}
```

[ui-grid  appscope](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/305_appScope)

Answer (score 0):

write input field inside div

```
cellTemplate: '<div><input  type="checkbox" ng-click="grid.appScope.selectRow($event,row)"/></div>'
```